# Mac OS crashing when trying to plot using TkAgg backend

Tags: python

My computer logs me out ("crashes") when I try to plot using the TkAgg backend (see example below). I am using mojave 10.14.6 and python 3.7.3.

```py
from sys import platform as sys_pf
if sys_pf == 'darwin':
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
x = [1,2,3]
# up to here the code does not cause a crash
plt.figure()
pl.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue. 
The only fix I have now is to use

```
matplotlib.use("MacOSX")
```

Comment: did you manage to find out the solution? I have the same issue. I am now using qt5agg, which works. but the problem is my console is really really slow! "MacOSX" doesnt work for me. Strangely it works on another Mac I have which uses High Sierra and python 3.7.3